# Could anyone tell me if this EFI should be listed like this

Tags: partition

Having had a mess up on a fresh install I somehow messed it up and got a blank volume that I could not get rid of.
Stabbing in the dark as I haven't got a clue really, I came across a thread on a similar thing.
Gave it ago in terminal and it went.
I now have it looking like this..
I realise the recovery partition has gone but this is what I also wanted to do as I want to do a complete fresh install.
After all that long winded text, can anyone tell me if the part that lists EFI should it list it twice as it is in the screen capture or should it just be a single EFI listed...hope anyone can follow that.
Thanks for any replies.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where your EFI partition is listed twice.

What I **do** see is that your EFI partition is named EFI, perhaps you were seeing that?

At the top of the `diskutil list` command, the first row is a header row that acts as a legend for the columns below: Number (#), TYPE, NAME, SIZE and IDENTIFIER.

Type and name are the same thing, which is how it usually is: the EFI partition is *called* EFI.

Note that in some situations I have seen an EFI partition with no name. It doesn't need a name to work, but macOS needs to recognize it as an EFI partition for the Mac to be bootable.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think I explained it clearly....not unusual for me. You see where EFI is, there are two side by side so it looks like this  EFI  EFI I have seen some pictures on the web where there is only one...hope that is a bit better. Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: If there is only one (under type) then the EFI partition was not given a name. Or if there is no "EFI" under the type column then it is not recognized by macOS as an EFI partition